# PHP - Image output: strange string

Tags: php, html, sql, mysql

I have to output a series of random images previously saved inside a DB.
At the moment of the output, instead print a picture, the code print a strange string (meaby dumpfile?):

```
(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢Š(¢¢’ú~ü±®æIüa¤Äû[SÓÕºàÜ¦'$·›ØÒ¢°o>)xvÀŸ7ZÓ×“þULünð®ì.±„ðFíŸÉj=¬íìæöLê¨®6ãã¦‡êW8b³|ÄâªŸÚL-…Óu¦ÇRmÕ@ÿÇª^"’ûH¯cQô;Ê+ÏeøýC£Ý:ó÷çHÏåTnh[­¿»ÐãRz/Ïýò¦£ë”—_ÌW©Øõ +Écý µIæùltuà¯Údfúgg_Â´­ÿh1ÿMÓ?O&à¹ü™ùÒXÊ/¯æSÂÔ]H¢¼õi £mœÝ[°ë¹Pãòlþ•¥iñïÂwmµudVÎèd~;qúÖ‘ÄR{IèT_e…‹iñ#Ã÷»|½kKfnŠnQXþæµ­î£»ŒFßµ¦´ÖëöÏôpND;W?ÝL…V9à'5ÏSK–GE<,çhŸNîWÏºoÇu·\ëW–¹É˜Í ¯ÕÖRºgß½^“Äñ_D¬ºÕ×™ÈÿM‘”þ$°üy¬þ¹…}R]Ot¨n5;{?õ×Åþû…þuóî¦öîònû»,ñ³Ãþ†¨ËtÖŸô    €ò“üÿLGþ5/ýÒãƒ¿Sè¼s¢Û¶×Ö4µoF»ŒZ‚‰:°ùµK^ÿp—þUàªI(eä{z ³œÁyú`U9V5>c¤…T‚7ØÉz®EG×¥Øµƒ]Yï|nð¼ƒª+Ù ‘èµ¿41þ«í·î@WÿBÅxŒ­ªmÿH½ó±)_ å³O·˜Jî±ÚÝ6:eb…‰õû£ô¨xéô±_S‡™ì§ãréÚ§# 7’3ÿ‘*´¿­óˆ´é™²Ïqÿ"kËžÂiUzÛ«­rƒóÀþ•Nh$óTIçÎPmn§Àú€ê?J—Œ¨RÂÀõi~:ÜÿË=Y¼oT5Vããn´Ì='O…›§uŸýšòñ£GqüVJ­ü|ÓÏ³1Ç¥8h&7GjÁ;maíÇ9ÅfñU{”°Ô»_yè—µhŸC·œ€ÿÌ·ôª³üsÔ¤ÿW¨i¬Ýˆ+üëˆ&ÞÏ8¸’>p°R3þî)ñ[­óñ%ño{–eÿÐ‡Yªú—õzk¡ÖIñ{W½UªH¥€ÿWj}ú*§7Å@îó5«ÍÃÑZ1ü¿•ssè6¨Û¦U™¾ñÃ– }2ÇóÅ8-¸m¶²dÿN¨ÓŒÔ:•V5NšÙÒüGšBÊ××ó?ç´Ÿ úV|þ&þÐ™n$QÔõÇJlSB]•¡‡o\;·õëS‰]¢†=¸àˆœ¨={ŸåëÞ£ß{²’ŠÙ÷¬Ï»ì3Éè¼ûöÜjIDiá¤Ä«Û|hÌ?J-æ˜Ûå)çæ…rãüõ©Ròt’B­œÿ¬‰8úýj,Ê¿b8šêÕwCco©þ€h¼Ôµgý\kï'ò;³ú~U$º
```

My code:

```
<?php
 include_once('conn.php');


 $n="SELECT COUNT('id_product')
 FROM 'products'";
 $value=mysql_query($n);

 do
 {
 $selectionASC='SELECT id_product 
        FROM products 
        ORDER BY id_product ASC
        LIMIT 1';
 $selectionDESC='SELECT id_product 
         FROM products 
         ORDER BY id_product DESC
         LIMIT 1';
  $ASC=mysql_query($selectionASC)
    or die ('Impossible execute the query <br />').mysql_error();
  $DESC=mysql_query($selectionDESC)
    or die ('Impossible execute the query <br />').mysql_error();

  //____________________________________________________________________
  $ASC = mysql_num_rows($ASC);
  $DESC = mysql_num_rows($DESC);

  $rand_n=rand(($ASC-1),($DESC+1));

  //____________________________________________________________________
  $selected='SELECT id_product,name, price, img
         FROM products
         WHERE id_product='.$rand_n;
  $selected = mysql_query($selected);
  //____________________________________________________________________

    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($selected))
        {
            echo "Product'id: &nbsp"; echo $row[0];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Name: &nbsp"; echo $row[1];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Price:: &nbsp"; echo $row[2];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Immage: <img src='images/".$row['3']."'alt='Image'>";
            echo '<hr> <br />';

            $value--;
        }
      }
       while ($value==0)
      ?>
```

The rest of the output is coherent with the code. Anyone know why it happen? And how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Does the database contain the filename of the image, or the actual binary data of the image?

Comment: Sidenote: Remove the quotes in `FROM 'products'` or wrap with backticks.

Comment: It contain the binary data of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot output image like what you did , first of things

when you fetch image from db .

for example if my image filed stored in img field i will call it like this

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("select * from img where img id=$id ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$img = $row['img'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $img;
```

so this page only for displaying the pictures  and when you want to use it you can do

```
<img src="display_img.php?id=2" />
```

it's not possible to keep every things in one page but also you can divide  your page like this

```
if($$_GET['action']=="display_img"){


// show img code 

}
```